# How to get same JSON string output on iOS and Rails?

Tags: objective-c, ruby, json, string, character-encoding

I have a JSON document on iOS and an identical document in Rails.  When I serialize it on iOS, I need it to be character-for-character equivalent to the serialized string from Rails.  However, when I try this, the outputs are mostly the same, but not quite.

On iOS:

```
id jsonObj;
NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:jsonObj options:0 error:nil];
NSString *string = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

On the Ruby side:

```
jsonObj // contains exactly the same content as the objc version
string = JSON.generate(jsonObj)
```

The issue I'm having is that Ruby's JSON.generate() doesn't output a JSON string in the same format as NSJSONSerialization on iOS.  Is there any way to make them behave the same?  Or is there another serialization method I can use to get consistent results on iOS and Rails?

One difference between the two that I spotted was that the original object had the text "N/A" in it.  Rails outputs this as-is, while iOS escapes it to "N\ /A".  Is there another string encoding option I can use on the iOS side to fix this?

**Edit:**

Here's a better example:

```
id json = @{ @"str": @"N/A" };
NSError *error = nil;
NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:json options:0 error:&error];
NSString *jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSLog(@"jsonString = '%@'", jsonString);
// prints "jsonString = '{"str":"N\/A"}'"
```

And the ruby equivalent:

```
json = { "str" => "N/A" }
jsonString = JSON.generate(json)
puts "jsonString = '#{jsonString}'"
// prints "jsonString = '{"str":"N/A"}'"
```

I also wrote both outputs to files and compared them again, with the same results.

Comment: How did you find out that the outputs were different?

Comment: I made an object (NSDictionary of NSStrings) on iOS and compared its json output to the json output from the same thing on the ruby side (Hash of Strings).  I think it's a string encoding issue, but I'm not sure how to fix it.

Comment: I think it's a string display matter, not string content issue.

Comment: I just edited the question to give better example code.  I thought it might be a display issue at first as well, but I wrote both to files, then compared them and they were different.